# JQuery: URL is opening twice - how to only open once?

Tags: jquery

I have a table in which the rows are clickable.  Also within the row I have a clickable button.  Both when clicked open a new window and the same URL.
The clickable row is achieved by JQuery.
The clickable button by HTML. (in case javascript disabled)
How can I stop the URL opening twice ie when the button within the row is clicked?  I have tried boolean logic but could not get it to work i.e the  and button still need to be functional even after clicking the button once.

I am very new to Javascript and Jquery.  Many Thanks.  Pls find my code below:

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myTable tr').click(function() {
        var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        if (href) {
          window.open(href);
        }
    });

});
```

the HTML code:

```
<td>
 <a href="some link" target="_blank">
  <img src="image.jpg"/>
 </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, but `preventDefault()` stops the default behavior of link `$('a').click(function(e) {      e.preventDefault();    });`

Comment: Your description of the problem does not match your markup.  Having something inside an anchor tag does not make it a "button".  A button is a form element.  If you did in fact have a seperate button that would make it a more interesting question, but you did receive the answer to how you would disable the default behavior of your anchor tag. However, considering that you're doing the same thing with the javascript as target _blank does, it makes one wonder why the javascript?

Comment: Hi, thank-you but not what i was after - i think.  i should have said clickable image instead of button - sorry.  when i click the image the new window opens twice.  The solution above does not prevent this.  Unless I am using it wrong.  The reason I am using jquery is so that the whole row is clickable not just the image within the row. Any ideas? @gview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, I took another look at this and realized the original nugget of advice was correct, but that the child link is the one that needs to have its default behavior prevented.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('#myTable tr td a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();        
  });
  $('#myTable tr').click(function() {
    var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    if (href) {
      window.open(href);
    }
  });
});
```

Looking back at the comments Usman suggested this.

Comment: Thank-you very much.  This works great.  Much obliged. @gview

Comment: @kad: Glad to hear it.  You can click on this answer to indicate it solved your problem, which is helpful for people searching past questions.

Answer (score 6):

event.preventDefault() will stop any default actions from being executed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myTable tr').click(function(event) {
        var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        if (href) {
          window.open(href);
          event.preventDefault();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi, thank-you but not what i was after - i think. i should have said clickable image instead of button - sorry. when i click the image the new window opens twice. The solution above does not prevent this. Unless I am using it wrong. The reason I am using jquery is so that the whole row is clickable not just the image within the row. Any ideas? @Andreas

Comment: @kad Uhm, do you have any link we could test? Unless I'm mistaken the above should work... unless your issue is that when you click OUTSIDE the a/img, it still opens twice. In that case you are running the script twice for some reason. A link would be handy though.

Comment: Hi Andreas, here is the link:

Comment: Here is the link: [link](http://moneycheckerpen.com/kad-design/ClickTest.html) @Andreas Many thanks.

Comment: @kad I just checked your link, and then ran `$("#myTable td").click(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });` and it worked perfectly. I would recommend that you take my initial code example and switch `tr` for `td` and it should work. It seems `tr` doesn't play nice.

Comment: Thank-you but it still does not work for me?  Now the other cells ie A to D dont go to the URL and the image when clicked still generates two windows.  Any other ideas? @Andreas

Comment: @kad Well, they way you are doing it is kind of strange to me. Regardless, the simplest solution really is for you to just ADD the following to your script `$('#myTable a').click(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });` (use your original code without preventDefault) ... that will prevent the A-tag from opening the window itself, and always have the TR-tag do it instead.